# Using flick4java in a webapp

Tags: java, flickr

I have done a few tests with flick4java, in command-line applications; but I need to include it in a webapp. I was wondering how to redirect to the flickr authorisation page, and have it redirect to a callback url.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you asking about how add oauth authorization to your app?

Comment: Yes, using flickr4java (and scribe)